# How do I filter a django queryset based on pairs of fields from another queryset?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a table that handles ordering of tasks, and each user can have a different order for the same task. This might be difficult to explain, so I have a discrete example at the bottom of this post.

Object representing the order of tasks for each user:

```
class TaskOrdering(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='ordering')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='task_ordering')
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

When I delete a task, I need to decrement the order of all tasks in each user's view that have an order greater than the deleted task's order. However, this deleted task's order is different for each user since they have their own view of the task list.

Right now I am doing:

```
# Instance is a Task object
def perform_destroy(self, instance): 

    # deleted_task_ordering is a set of TaskOrdering objects
    # representing the order of the task in EACH user's view
    deleted_task_ordering = instance.ordering.all()

    # deleted_task_ordering is a set of TaskOrdering objects
    # representing the order of OTHER tasks in EACH user's view
    other_tasks_ordering = TaskOrdering.objects.exclude(task=instance)

    for o in deleted_task_ordering:
        need_decrement = other_tasks_ordering.filter(user=o.user, order__gt=o.order)
        need_decrement.update(order=F('order') - 1)
```

This works, but there must be a more efficient way by using django queries instead of a for loop. The reason I am struggling is because the `TaskOrdering` queryset filter would need to match pairs of fields from `deleted_task_ordering`. I know I could also build the filter query in a loop and do one bulk update, but I'm trying to get rid of the for loop all-together.

For example, if a task was deleted that had 3 users, the `deleted_task_ordering` might be:

```
[
    {task: 1, user: 1, order: 3},
    {task: 1, user: 2, order: 5},
    {task: 1, user: 3, order: 2}
]
```

Then I would need my `TaskOrdering` filter to return all objects where:

```
User = 1 AND order > 3 +
User = 2 AND order > 5 +
User = 3 AND order > 3
```

I really hope I explained this well enough!

Comment: why do you need to play with the task order index? As long as you add at the bottom  you shouldn't have issues sorting them in the correct fashion.

Comment: @t.stv Yes you are correct, in the case of deleting it would still sort correctly, but I have other cases where I would need to do this same loop anyway. For example, if a task is moved to the top of a column, I'd need to push everything down.

Regardless, I'd love to know how to handle this case in a general sense!

Comment: you can take a linked list approach